# Menu Button OpenCart php

Tags: php, menu, opencart

I have tried to add a custom menu button in two different languages

I use the default template

I have edited these files inside my OpenCart main folder:

1. header.tpl on /catalog/view/theme/yourthemefolder/template/common
2. header.php on /catalog/language/english and /catalog/language/yourlanguage
3. header.php on /catalog/controller/common

and added these lines

1

```
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx/shop/index.php?route=product/manufacturer"><?php echo $new_gamintojai; ?></a></li>
```

2

```
$_['new_gamintojai'] = 'Brands';
```

3

```
$this->data['new_gamintojai'] = $this->language->get('new_gamintojai');
```

I can click on the button, but there is no text. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okey I have figured it out myself.

Have changed this line :

```
$this->data['new_gamintojai'] = $this->language->get('new_gamintojai');
```

to

```
$data['new_gamintojai'] = $this->language->get('new_gamintojai');
```